# Why is the IRB prompt changing to an askerisk when I try to match this regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am a newbie in Ruby, I'm using version 1.9.3. I have the following regular expression:

```
/\\\//
```

As far as I know, it should match a string which has the characters `'\'` and `'/'`, one following the other, right?

I am using the following code in order to get `true` in case the regex matches the string or symbol in the far right:

```
!(regex !~ :"string or symbol to match")
```

Because using `=~` gives me the index of the match and I simply want a boolean. Besides, I'm trying to see how ugly or hackish can Ruby look compared to C :P

When I try to match the symbol `:\/` the IRB prompt changes to an asterisk, and returns nothing. Why?

When I try to match the string `"\/"` my little ugly snippet returns false. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol `:\/` is not a valid symbol. You could do `:'\/'` if you wanted a symbol version of the string `'\/'`. And when you feed it `"\/"` it is false because that has double quotes so it is actually the string `'/'` so you actually want either `'\/'` or `"\\/"`.

Finally, it's better code and convention to do your test like so:

```
!!(regex =~ :'\/')
!!(regex =~ '\/')
!!(regex =~ "\\/")
```